# date_create_from_format created Date seen as boolean

Tags: php, time

I would like to read out some times from my database and remove all entries where a field is (as seen in time) older than now. 
This is my current code:

```
//$eSonderPreis->R_GLTBISDATUM = 30.12.1899
$bisDatum = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $eSonderPreis->R_GLTBISDATUM);
//var_dump returns: [...] string(19) "1899-12-30 00:00:00" [...]
var_dump(date_timestamp_get($bisDatum));
//var_dump returns: boolean false
echo " - ";
var_dump($thetime);
//var_dump returns: current time as int

if(date_timestamp_get($bisDatum) < $thetime)
{
    unset($aData[$key]);
}
```

date_timestamp_get returns false, which means that it failed (according to the docs). Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is before Unix Epoch time (01/01/1970), `date_timestamp_get()` will return false.

You can use format("U") instead to get the time:

```
echo $bisDatum->format("U");
```

There's some information about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Specifically for your code:

```
if($bisDatum->format("U") < $thetime)
{
    unset($aData[$key]);
}
```